# Clean all files except target in maven

Tags: java, maven-3

In maven is it possible to clean all files inside project directory except target directory after maven compile step? How can I setup this?

My requirement is something like this -

1. I run maven compile command which generates classes file under target directory.
2. Now I want to copy only generated target folder and pom.xml to another directory and build jar/war from that location, can I do something like this?

Also can maven copy a external properties file(outside of project) to projects WEB-INF/classes folder?

Comment: I have to ask. _**Why**_ do you want to do that????

Comment: clean all files? So also the source files!?

Comment: Yes, I would like to clean all files or would like to copy target folder to another location, where I can do a package without recompiling. This is special requirement so I have to do.